Close MAUI CommunityToolkit Popup with BackButton on Android
We are using the MAUI CommunityToolkit to open a popup as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup
How can we on Android listen to the back button and close the Popup whenever the user clicks the Back button (hardware button on device). We have tried this method as described here Reset xamarin.forms.shell to initial page on back button but cannot get that to work on a CommunityToolkit popup.

Are you using shell?

I create a project and use CommunityToolkit popup. But the popup can be closed by clicking BackButton successfully. Could you provide a minimal, reproducible example to reproduce?

Hum that is not working for us, will test again

Well, could you provide a minimal, reproducible example to reproduce?


How can we on Android listen to the back button

public partial class ContentPageTEST : ContentPage
{
    public ContentPageTEST ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        // YOUR CODE TO CLOSE PopUp
        //...
        //...
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();  
    }
}


This doesn't work within the Popup page. The Popup is meant to be handling Closing itself in the new CommunityToolkit, but it doesn't have the OnBackButtonPressed event.
